# Does Mocha need a server to run tests in a browser?

Tags: javascript, testing, mocha.js

I'm confused about how Mocha should be setup to run tests in the browser. I've setup some command line tests which run fine with 'mocha' in the terminal. I've also setup a test.html page that is supposed to load 'mocha.css' and 'mocha.js' (http://mochajs.org/#browser-support).

It seems mocha has to be running as a server for the duration of the tests in order for mocha.js and mocha.css to load.

Is there another app that must act as an intermediary?

Comment: Your original question was too broad. What you were asking could have been answered in dozens of different ways, none really better than the other. Someone would say use tools A, B and someone else would cay C, D and the third would say A, D, and other permutations. It amounts to asking people to suggest tools, which is not a good fit for SO.

Comment: @louis no, it's not an overly broad question. It's a very *specific* question that has not been clearly answered, anywhere. I've been looking, reading, and fiddling. I dislike even asking questions on SO anymore because someone always pops up with exactly your mind of unhelpful comment.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, there is no app that *must* act as an intermediary.

For one of my applications I just had a `test.html` file that contained what the Mocha documentation tells you to do, plus whatever customization I needed for my project. I just loaded it in my browser by opening the file with the "Open File" option in the menu of my browser and it worked.

However... if you want to perform AJAX calls either you have to mock the whole thing so that no AJAX is *actually* performed or you have to have a test server. So now I have a minimal server that I made using [Express](http://expressjs.com/).

Comment: What you're saying doesn't make sense though. You can't just load the test.html and expect it to work. It loads mocha.css and .js from somewhere, and since the files aren't local to the test.html file mocha has to run a server.

Comment: It loads them from the file system.